# How to fully replace Windows8 with Ubuntu on Acer Iconiq w700?

Tags: acer

I want to get rid of the Windows8 that is installed on Acer Iconia w700 tablet and fully replace it with Ubuntu as a main and only OS on the tablet.

I understand that there will be some issues with configuring the hardware, but I have to try.

Do I need to connect other than the native keyboard and USB Mouse to complete the process?

I understand my questions is probably very lame but I`d very much appreciate if someone explain to me the steps of the process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu). Desktop Ubuntu is generally not designed for tablets, so this may not be a good idea without a bit more research. Create a LiveUSB and use the "Try Ubuntu" environment to test Ubuntu on your hardware before committing to an install.

Comment: Thanx! I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Download Ubuntu and copy it to an USB stick. 
For detailed tutorial see: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Start from your USB stick and follow the installation process. There you can choose »erase disk and install Ubuntu«.
Take a look here: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0